# What is the smallest number k, such that $k^{2014}+2014$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the smallest number k, such that

$$k^{2014}+2014$$

is prime ? I checked upto $k= 24000$ and did not find a prime.

Since the numbers do not grow very fast ($k=92204$ produces a $10 000$-digit number),
the smallest k should be not too big.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe there is one?

Comment: Only a heuristic one. Since there seems to be no factor dividing all numbers and since the numbers grow slow enough, it seems that such a prime exists.

Comment: Also, I cannot see algebraic factors. But of course, I am not sure, that such a prime exists.

Comment: As the polynomial $x^{2014}+2014$ is irreducible over the integers, standard number theory conjectures (Bateman-Horn, Schinzel's Hypothesis H) predict that there are infinitely many integers $k$ for which $k^{2014}+2014$ is prime.

Comment: PS: $x^{2014}+2014$ is irreducible thanks to Eisenstein's criterion. The first year from now where the corresponding polynomial is reducible over the integers is in nearly five centuries: $x^{2500}+2500 = \left(x^{1250}-10 x^{625}+50\right) \left(x^{1250}+10 x^{625}+50\right)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenPFGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/) reports that the the smallest probable prime is $$40205^{2014}+2014$$ (9274 digits).   Incidentally, it also found the probable primes $$57373^{2014}+2014$$ (9585 digits) and $$60983^{2014}+2014$$ (9638 digits).  All other smaller candidates are proven composite.

I got PGFW to run a bunch of probable prime tests, until I got bored.  Generating proof certificates for these numbers would be time-consuming.

Here's the PFGW output:

```
PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]

40205^2014+2014 is 3-PRP! (2.8436s+0.0006s)                                    
57373^2014+2014 is 3-PRP! (1.7727s+0.0002s)                                    
60983^2014+2014 is 3-PRP! (3.7931s+0.0002s)

PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]


***WARNING! file primes.txt may have already been fully processed.

40205^2014+2014 is 5-PRP! (3.6724s+0.0002s)                                    
57373^2014+2014 is 5-PRP! (1.7312s+0.0002s)                                    
60983^2014+2014 is 5-PRP! (2.9311s+0.0002s)

PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]


***WARNING! file primes.txt may have already been fully processed.

40205^2014+2014 is 7-PRP! (1.5628s+0.0002s)                                    
57373^2014+2014 is 7-PRP! (3.1911s+0.0002s)                                    
60983^2014+2014 is 7-PRP! (2.0266s+0.0006s)

PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]

Primality testing 40205^2014+2014 [N-1/N+1, Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge]                                    
Running N-1 test using base 7                                                  
Running N+1 test using discriminant 13, base 1+sqrt(13)                                    
Calling N-1 BLS with factored part 0.21% and helper 0.06% (0.70% proof)              40205^2014+2014 is Fermat and Lucas PRP! (10.4597s+0.0002s)                                    

PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]

Primality testing 57373^2014+2014 [N-1/N+1, Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge]                                    
Running N-1 test using base 5                                                  
Running N+1 test using discriminant 11, base 2+sqrt(11)                                    
Calling N-1 BLS with factored part 0.11% and helper 0.04% (0.36% proof)              57373^2014+2014 is Fermat and Lucas PRP! (11.0386s+0.0003s) 

PFGW Version 3.7.7.64BIT.20130722.x86_Dev [GWNUM 27.11]

Primality testing 60983^2014+2014 [N-1/N+1, Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge]                                    
Running N-1 test using base 5                                                  
Running N+1 test using discriminant 17, base 1+sqrt(17)                                    
Calling N+1 BLS with factored part 0.14% and helper 0.00% (0.42% proof)              60983^2014+2014 is Fermat and Lucas PRP! (9.6654s+0.0005s)
```