# What is the least number $n$, such that $n^{2015}+2015$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the least number $n$, such that $n^{2015}+2015$ is prime ?

According to my calculations, there is no prime for $n\le 6000$.

It is clear, that $n$ must be even, since $n^{2015}+2015$ must be odd.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/663884/

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one seems to be $n=9462$ (according to Mathematica), i.e.
$$
9462^{2015}+2015
$$
is prime. I have no good mathematical arguments for this, though.

The code I used to get this was:

```
 n=2;
 While[Not[PrimeQ[n^2015 + 2015]], Print[n]; n = n + 2]
```

It stoped at 9460. Just to be sure, I ran

```
 PrimeQ[9462^2015+2015]
```

and the response was `True`.

Comment: I trust mathematica. Thank you very much.

Comment: PARI/GP is very slow indeed. I am currently at $n=7398$.

Comment: Does primeq prove a number to be prime ?

Comment: Thank you for selecting the answer, I'm happy for it. I'm not sure it should be selected, though. What if someone comes up with a mathematical argument?

Comment: This chance is very, very low! Very little is known about the structure of such big primes!

Comment: As far as the docum. entation says, it yields `True` if one enters a prime, yes: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeQ.html

Comment: Probably, it is a probable-prime-test, but it is almost certain that a number detected  as prime is really prime.

Comment: @Peter There are tests that answer "definitely composite" or "probably prime". An dthere arte tests that answer "probably composite" or "definitely prime". As far as I know, the return `PrimeQ` can be interpreted as "definitely prime" or "definitely composite" because it combines both kinds of test until a definite answer is obtained.

Comment: Normally, the result "composite" is $100$% true, the result "prime" is very very likely true.